# Create new StateCode in CRM 4.0

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I have a situation where i have to add a new State to the stateCodes list. I would like to add "Fired" to Active and InActive state, How can i do such a thing ?

Note: i know about the StatusCode and how to use it but i want to use the statecode.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't. State codes are very tightly controlled. In the UI, there are only going to be options for activating and deactivating a record, so CRM doesn't allow you to add any new ones. Your best option is probably just to add it to the possible statuscode values for your entity.

Answer (score 1):

Well, i couldn't find anyway to do what i want except the dirty way, which is to open the CRM database and add a new StateCode which is not recommended from Microsoft by the way.

This Query may help you to find the suitable attributes.

http://blogs.inetium.com/blogs/azimmer/archive/2010/02/08/status-codes-when-deactivating-records-in-crm-4-0.aspx

Thank you Matt.

Have a nice day :)